# Error apt-get install: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: raspbian, apt

I have this raspberry PI 2, which I run Resilio and SSH for backups. I installed a couple of stuff without any issue (APCUPSD, web interface for APCUPSD, apache2).

I am trying to install RPI-Monitor and webmin, but I always get: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

```
 Depends: libnet-ssleay-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libauthen-pam-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libio-pty-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: apt-show-versions but it is not going to be installed
```

if I try to install them, i get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-show-versions : Depends: libapt-pkg-perl (>= 0.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
 libauthen-pam-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libio-pty-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Can you please give also the command line you use to install?

Answer (score 1):

Try running these commands: 
`sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
(assuming you have sudo access)

source:[Linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-fix-broken-package-904637/)

Comment: [link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-fix-broken-package-904637/)

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` Please edit your answer, for best reading